# Need help understanding a short batch script (possible scam)

Tags: file, batch-file

A friend of mine received some "tech support" from a questionable source and they left a batch file on his computer entitled "Junk Remover".  I am suspicious of the batch file but I have no idea what the batch is doing.  I was hoping someone could shine some light on what is going on when this batch is run.

```
@echo off
FOR /F "tokens=1,2*" %%V IN ('bcdedit') DO SET adminTest=%%V
IF (%adminTest%)==(Access) goto noAdmin
for /F "tokens=*" %%G in ('wevtutil.exe el') DO (call :do_clear "%%G")
echo.
echo goto theEnd
:do_clear
echo clearing %1
wevtutil.exe cl %1
goto :eof
:noAdmin
exit
```

Thanks in advance for anyone taking a look and help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure this question is on topic for Stack Overflow, but based on the outputs of bcdedit /? and wevtutil /? (plus some googling), all this script seems to do is check to make sure the script is running as an Administrator and then if it is, deletes a bunch of Event Viewer logs. Nothing malicious.

Comment: Thank you for the info somethingdark.  Sorry if this is not the relevant forum for this, I was unsure as to where best to ask such a question.

Comment: If they are clearing event viewer I would think they did something nefarious and are erasing their bread crumb trail.

Comment: Or they figure most people don't look at event viewer and they're trying to free up some space. Never attribute to malice what can be explained by stupidity.